# why "dir /B file.eps|del " is wrong?

Tags: windows, command-line, pipe

There is a file named "file.eps" in the current directory, and I want to delete this file. I know I can simple use

```
del file.eps
```

But I just can't understand why

```
dir /B file.eps|del
```

didn't work. `dir /B file.eps` gives exactly the file, and it should be transferred to `del` through the pipe.

Comment: You probably need to use `> del` to _redirect_ the output

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name why? I tried, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

del can't use inputs like a list or a redirective.

For example, a file list.txt including all filenames to be deleted, can't be processed in a way like `del < list.txt`.

So, your syntax is correct, but the problem is del.